# ASIDownloadCache is not updated with new content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4, asihttprequest

Following is the source code for Downloading and Caching images from remote server using ASIHTTPRequest. If server is not updated with new images im using cached copy of the image. It's caching all the images in initial request and it's working fine.

As per below code it's supposed to check server whether new contents available every time. I checked server logs and it's printing 304 status code. But when I updated with latest images it won't show up with new image. instead of it's showing cached image. But server logs says it is sending new image by status code 200. To avoid this behavior i have to delete the app and re-install it.

```
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
request.timeOutSeconds = kDefaultTimeInterval;
request.validatesSecureCertificate = NO;
[request setDownloadCache:[ASIDownloadCache sharedCache]];
[request setCachePolicy:ASIAskServerIfModifiedCachePolicy];
[request setCacheStoragePolicy:ASICachePermanentlyCacheStoragePolicy];
[request setSecondsToCache:kSecondsToCache];
[request startSynchronous];

if (![request didUseCachedResponse]) {
    NSLog(@"  Cache miss.  Loading resource %@", location);
} else {
    NSLog(@"  Cache hit!");
}
NSLog(@" ***  image data size: %u bytes", [request.responseData length]);
return ([request error]) ? nil : request.responseData;
```

what i'm missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured out what happend in there by myself. It's just a stupid mistake and mis understanding of the API.

By seconds to cache, I was thinking it's for keep cache until value set. But seems it's not. As per the documentation

```
Set secondsToCache on the request to override any expiry date for the content
set by the server, and store this response in the cache until secondsToCache 
seconds have elapsed
```

So it's overriding value set by the server. So even if server updated with new contents and if the expiry date set for request doesn't expired the local copy will be used.

As a fix I just removed line `[request setSecondsToCache:kSecondsToCache];`